# can I make an <h1> tag as a clickable button that functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

The web page I am making consists of

```html
<div class="cane-wrap">
        <h1 class="mc">christmas tic tac toe</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

on top centre of the web and autoplay going on the background using JS.

I have successfully hid the play button using `style="display:none;"`  but shortly after realized I can't turn the music off. how do I **make `<div><h1>` as a clickable button** so that I can **turn on/off the music**?

after some googling I found some sources that turn div into buttons but can `<h1>` be a button as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can use this tag like a button. If your button will work as a counter - `on/off`, then I advise you to use the `toggleAttribute()` method inside the click event, with which you can control the attribute of the music playback activity.

I have provided a code that you can use.

Instead of a `selector` - you need to specify a `class`, `id` or `tag` that plays the music.

And instead of the `'attribute'` - the name of the attribute responsible for the state of the music playback activity.

```
let on_off = document.querySelector('.cane-wrap .mc');

on_off.onclick = function() {
  selector.toggleAttribute('attribute');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can make an `h1` element clickable by all means. I'm doing that in the snippet below. You'll just have to add a click event listener to the element in order to achieve that:

```js
document.querySelector('.mc').addEventListener('click', function(){
console.log('h1 has been clicked');
});
```

```css
.mc:active{
transform: scale(1, 0.9);
color:#2d3436;
transition: transform 0.2s color 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="mc" >This is a header</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by using `jQuery`. You can do it like this:

```
    <div class="cane-wrap">
          <h1 class="mc" id = "myID">christmas tic tac toe</h1>
    </div>
```

and then write some codeto create its click function

```
 $("#myID").on("click", function(){
       //do something here ...
 })
```

If you are using vanilla js then use eventListerner to listen to the click event for your h1 tag.

Comment: this will work only when using jquery. the question is not tagged with jquery